# Backbone.js - base path not concat with subpaths

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

In my base collection i have the base path, from the base path i am extending further urls.. but while i console the url in the extended collection i am not getting the full path of the url..

instead just i am getting the url - what the extended collection have.. why i am getting like so, and what should be the proper approach?

here is my try :

```
BaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    path: 'http://path/to/api'
});

TeachersCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    url:"xyz/abc",
    initialize:function(){
        console.log(this.url);//xyz/abc - why i am getting like this instead of full path?
        //full url should be 'http://path/to/api/xyz/abc' - how can i get like this..?
    }
});

var x = new TeachersCollection;
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SrNNV/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `path` is not a special property on any of Backbone's classes
2. Models can have `urlRoot`, but there's no such thing for collections

[Here's an approach that should work for you](http://jsfiddle.net/SrNNV/2/):

```
TeachersCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    url:function() {
        return this.path + "/xyz/abc"
    },
    initialize:function(){
        // this.url = _.result(this, 'url');
        console.log(_.result(this, 'url'));
    }
});
```

You may actually want to think about changing the constructor on your base collection, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/SrNNV/3/) if you're going to be extending it a lot:

```
BaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    constructor: function() {
        this.url = 'http://path/to/api' + this.url;
        Backbone.Collection.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

TeachersCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    url: "/xyz/abc",
    initialize:function(){
        console.log(this.url);//xyz/abc
        //full url should be 'http://path/to/api/xyz/abc'
    }
});

var x = new TeachersCollection;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use a function for [`url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url), then you could do things like this:

```
TeachersCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return this.path + '/xyz/abc';
    },
    //...
```

The problem with trying to use just a string for `url` in such cases is getting the right `this` so that you can look up the `path`. You could go through `BaseCollection.prototype`:

```
TeachersCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    url: BaseCollection.prototype.path + '/xyz/abc',
    //...
```

but that's pretty cumbersome and noisy, I don't think saving the overhead of a function call is worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write this code:

```
console.log(this.path+this.url)
```

Comment: I can write like that, but while i fetch the data, it should fetch from full path right..? (this is not just consoling, i need to fetch the data using my base url)

Comment: Yes, of course.
I think its an external api, so you can use this thing-